# adding the details in one form and details will be updated in another form

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

I have two forms.. form1 and form2 in form1 i have gridview  with three columns and in form2 i have two buttons one is add button and second one is update button and i have three text boxes ...

i have done like this if we click any of grid view column in form1 then the form 2 will be displayed with textboxes fill with grid view row values ..

now i need to add another row to gridview by using this add button in form 2 .. so when i fill the textboxes and click on add button the form 2 will be closed and the form 1 grid view is update automatically with these details  ...

i am using winforms application and using linq to entites for doing databse operations ..

any idea pls.... for doing this...

Comment: seems very awkward unless I am not getting something;  why do you need two forms?  I assume this is an MDI application, no? What's wrong with using 1 Form and using a splitter, or break the form in to two panels and hide "form 2" as necessary?

Comment: @gangelo its not a mdi application i need two forms .. like ecommerce application  so.. if you click on any shopping product  image then another form will open with particular shopping product...along with detials .. i need some thing like this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare event in form2 for AddRow, subscribe to that event in form1, when button clicked on form2  and new row have to be added, form2 raises that event, so form1 handles it and shows it on DataGrid.

Tutorial for event implementation you can find here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645739(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: Writing from mobile, so not now, but follow the link you will find there a lot of it.

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding your question you need to do the following:

1. You need to create a click event for your 'Add' button that will add the new record to your database.
2. Once the record is added you can close your form and on your form close you can refresh the datagrid in Form1.

I do something similar to this in several of my applications. On Form1 when opening Form2 you can create something like this:

```
private void ShowForm2()
{
    DialogResult addResult = new Form2().ShowDialog();

    if (addResult == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        //your code to populate your datagrid
    }
}
```

Then on Form2 your Add button click

```
private void AddRecordButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
       // code to add the record to your database
       //then use the DialogResult   OK
       DialogResult = DialogResult.OK
    }
    catch
    {
       //if it fails set DialogResult to Abort
       DialogResult = DialogResult.Abort
    }

}
```

Comment: oh ok.. do i need to add click event handler for form2 so when i click on the add button it will automatically update the gridview in form1... is this right???